# How to view parameters on firebase console while logging custom event using firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

`await analytics().logEvent('event name', {user: 'ashley', userName: 'ashley123'})`
I want to see parameters user and username in firebase analytics event dashboard but only event name is shown...
Above is how I logged a custom event in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set up the [custom definitions](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209) on Firebase console > Events page to create custom dimensions and metrics.

- Custom dimensions are your event parameters with text value.
- Custom metrics are your event parameters with numeric value.

Note that the parameters will start to accumulate data after you register them on the console. It means that your previous data will not be included here.

You should see a card or chart on each event that will log the parameters.

For your case, you can add a custom dimension "user", then use a descriptive name that you want to see in the reports.